# Заполнение массива с клавиатуры Си

Tags: c, массивы

Не получается сделать ручное заполнение массива. Если убрать ={0..4};, то программа неправильно работает

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#define SWAP(T,a,b) do {T tmp = a; a=b; b=tmp;} while(0)

void print_matrix(int a[5][5])
{
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        printf("%2d", a[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
}

printf("\n");
printf("\n");

}

void main() {
int a[5][5] = { 0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4};
print_matrix(a);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    SWAP(int, a[4][i], a[0][i]);
}
print_matrix(a);
}
```

Comment: Компилирую код в Visual Studio

Comment: Нужно через консоль, чтобы пользователь сам заполнил его

Comment: `scanf()` вам в помощь...

Comment: Это то понятно, но куда его всунуть то? В цикл For он не дает компилировать
https://imgur.com/a/pfN2rDu

Comment: В тело второго (вложенного) `for` и всунь. Да аргументы запятой раздели.

Comment: Тоже не дает https://imgur.com/a/NBXNttd

Comment: Раздели запятой аргументы.  Если нужно больше одного оператора в теле цикла, то следует их объединить в блок с помощью фигурных скобок `{scanf_s(...); printf(...);}`.

Comment: А фигурные скобки Страуструпу писать оставили? :)